# Minimum window substring - LeetCode challenge

Tags: programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, swift

Below is my code for the [“Minimum Window Substring”](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/) LeetCode problem in Swift:

> Given a string S and a string T, find the minimum window in S which will contain all the characters in T in complexity O(n).
>
> **Example:**
>
> **Input:** S = "ADOBECODEBANC", T = "ABC"
> **Output:** "BANC

My solution fails on a very long string,  but passes all the other 267 cases apart from that. I can't figure out why the Leetcode online judge says time limit exceeded, my solution seems o(n), any help is much appreciated.

```
func minWindow(_ s: String, _ t: String) -> String {
        var end = 0
        var start = 0
        
        if s == "" || t == "" || s.count < t.count {
            return ""
        }
        
        var freq: [Character : Int] = [:]
        
        for curChar in t {
            if let val = freq[curChar] {
                freq[curChar] = val + 1
            } else {
                freq[curChar] = 1
            }
        }
        
        let stringArray = Array(s)
        
        var resStart = 0
        var resLen = Int.max
        
        var distinct = freq.keys.count
        
        while end < s.count {
            let curChar = stringArray[end]
            
            if let val = freq[curChar] {
                freq[curChar] = val - 1
                if val - 1 == 0 {
                    distinct -= 1
                }
            }
            
            while (distinct == 0) {
                if resLen > end - start {
                    resLen = end - start
                   resStart = start
                }

                let curStart = stringArray[start]
                if let val = freq[curStart] {
                    freq[curStart] = val + 1
                    if val + 1 > 0 {
                        distinct += 1
                    }
                }
                start += 1
            }
            
            end += 1
        }
        
        if resLen == Int.max {
            return ""
        } else {
            return String(stringArray[resStart...(resStart + resLen)])
        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: The condition `s.count < t.count` seems unjustified to me. IMHO `s="ABCD"` and `t="CBCBCBBCBBB"` is a valid input (the answer should be `"BC"`).

Comment: @CiaPan: The LeetCode description is a bit unclear, but according to https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/discuss/26825/Can-T-have-characters-repeating, repeated character in T must also occur repeatedly in the sliding window of S.

Comment: @MartinR Wow, that seems an additional level of difficulty. Didn't read, thank you for specifying this requirement here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Performance

The main culprit for exceeding the time limit is here:

```
while end < s.count { ... }
```

A Swift string is a `Collection` but not a `RandomAccessCollection`, so that the complexity of `var count` is \$ O(n) \$, where \$ n \$ is the number of characters in the string.

`s.count` is called on each iteration, so that the total complexity becomes  \$ O(n^2) \$.

Since you already converted the string to an array of characters, you can simply replace the condition by

```
while end < stringArray.count { ... }
```

Arrays are `RandomAccessCollection`s and determining their count is a \$ O(1) \$ operation. That should already improve the performance considerably for large strings.

An alternative is to iterate over/keep track of string *indices* instead, that makes the `stringArray` obsolete:

```
var start = s.startIndex // Start of current window
var end = s.startIndex // End of current window
var len = 0 // Length of current window

while end != s.endIndex {
    let curChar = s[end]
    s.formIndex(after: &end)
    len += 1

    // ...
}
```

#### Some simplifications

Testing for an empty string can be done with `isEmpty`:

```
if s.isEmpty || t.isEmpty || s.count < t.count {
    return ""
}
```

When building the frequency map you can use the dictionary subscripting with default value:

```
var freq: [Character : Int] = [:]
for curChar in t {
    freq[curChar, default: 0] += 1
}
```

and that can be further shorted using `reduce(into:)`:

```
var freq = t.reduce(into: [:]) { dict, char in
    dict[char, default: 0] += 1
}
```

#### Use `Optional` instead of magic values

Here

```
var resLen = Int.max
```

you are using a “magic value”: `Int.max` indicates that no matching window has been found so far. That works because the given strings are unlikely to have \$ 2^{63} - 1 \$ characters, but it forces you to use exactly the same “magic value” at

```
if resLen == Int.max { ... }
```

Also the initial value of

```
var resStart = 0
```

is meaningless, it will be overwritten as soon as the first matching window is found.

Magic values are frowned upon in Swift because there is a dedicated language feature for the purpose: the *optional* values.

```
var resLen: Int?
```

clearly indicates an undefined value, and later be tested with optional binding.

A (minor) drawback is that you no longer simply compare

```
if resLen > end - start { ... }
```

but I'll come back to that later.

#### Use `struct`s to combine related properties

Both the current and the best window are described by two properties (

```
var end = 0
var start = 0

var resStart = 0
var resLen = Int.max
```

or – with the above suggestion – by three properties

```
var start = s.startIndex // Start of current window
var end = s.startIndex // End of current window
var len = 0 // Length of current window

// Similar for best window ...
```

With a

```
struct StringWindow {
    var startIndex: String.Index
    var endIndex: String.Index
    var length: Int

    // ...
}
```

these related properties are nicely combined, and it makes the code more self-documenting:

```
var currentWindow = StringWindow(...)
var bestWindow: StringWindow?
```

Comparing the length against the optional `bestWindow` can be put into a method of that type, assigning a new best window is simply done with

```
bestWindow = currentWindow
```

and the final result can be determined with optional binding:

```
if let best = bestWindow {
    return String(s[best.startIndex..<best.endIndex])
} else {
    return ""
}
```

#### Putting it together

Putting all the above suggestions together the code could look like this:

```
func minWindow(_ s: String, _ t: String) -> String {

    struct StringWindow {
        var startIndex: String.Index
        var endIndex: String.Index
        var length: Int

        init(for string: String) {
            self.startIndex = string.startIndex
            self.endIndex = string.startIndex
            self.length = 0
        }

        func shorter(than other: StringWindow?) -> Bool {
            if let other = other {
                return length < other.length
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    if s.isEmpty || t.isEmpty || s.count < t.count {
        return ""
    }

    var freq = t.reduce(into: [:]) { dict, char in
        dict[char, default: 0] += 1
    }
    var distinct = freq.count

    var currentWindow = StringWindow(for: s)
    var bestWindow: StringWindow?

    while currentWindow.endIndex != s.endIndex {
        let curChar = s[currentWindow.endIndex]
        s.formIndex(after: &currentWindow.endIndex)
        currentWindow.length += 1

        if let val = freq[curChar] {
            freq[curChar] = val - 1
            if val - 1 == 0 {
                distinct -= 1
            }
        }

        while distinct == 0 {
            if currentWindow.shorter(than: bestWindow) {
                bestWindow = currentWindow
            }

            let curStart = s[currentWindow.startIndex]
            if let val = freq[curStart] {
                freq[curStart] = val + 1
                if val + 1 > 0 {
                    distinct += 1
                }
            }
            s.formIndex(after: &currentWindow.startIndex)
            currentWindow.length -= 1
        }
    }

    if let best = bestWindow {
        return String(s[best.startIndex..<best.endIndex])
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

#### Final remarks

- Try to use more descriptive variable names (what is `var distinct`) or at least document their meaning.
- Don't abbreviate variable names: use e.g. `length` instead of `len`, or `startIndex` instead of `start`.
- Determining the number of key/value entries in a dictionary can be simplified to

  ```
  var distinct = freq.count
  ```

  instead of `freq.keys.count`.
- The parentheses at

  ```
  while (distinct == 0) { ... }
  ```

  are not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the code improvements you've suggested.

Comment: I wasn't aware of formIndex and hence was using offsetBy for iterating through the string initially. That was leading to n^2 complexity, I changed it to an array but forgot to iterate the array instead of the string.